# javascript how to var newclass(in) = oldclass(null, in)?

Tags: javascript

Excuse me for not using any technical descriptions here as I am new to javascript.  But this is a simple question for anyone learned in javascript.

I am just trying to create a new class that takes only one argument from an existing one that takes two or more arguments.

```
var newclass(arg) = oldclass(1,"hello",arg); // newclass is pre-filled with 1 and "hello"
```

Therefore I want to essentially pre-fill the arguments so I may only have to pass one argument in. What is the proper way of doing this in javascript?

Comment: Are you trying to do currying / partial application in JavaScript? It is not clear to me what you are attempting here.

Comment: Just trying to do an exact clone of the old class but with 2 of the 3 arguments already filled.  The new class will only have to provide one arg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript doesnt support default parameters. You can do something along the lines of:

```
function newClass(arg) {
  return oldClass(1, "hello", arg);
}
```

or:

```
function oldClass(arg1, arg2, arg3) {
  arg2 = typeof arg2 !== 'undefined' ? arg2 : "hello";
  arg3 = typeof arg3 !== 'undefined' ? arg3 : 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/) is a very good example of how to create classes by John Resig.

Basically following his example your new class would be:

```
var newClass = Class.extend({
    init: function (args) {
        this._super(1, "hello", args);
    }
});
```